# Slimframework 404 issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, slim

I am experimenting with the Slimframework and having some trouble getting past square one.  My directory structure is as follows

```
/var/www/html
    rest
      .htaccess 
      index.php
      vendor
         composer
         slim
```

.htaccess contains the following

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php is as follows

```
<?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $app = new \Slim\Slim();
 $app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {echo "Hello, $name";});
 $app->run();
 //echo 'xx';
?>
```

When I browse to example.com/rest/index.php

I get a 404 error.  I have ensured that my Apache configuration allows .htaccess so that is not the issue.  I assume that I am overlooking something quite elementary but I am unable to spot it.  I'd much appreciate any help.

Comment: And what happens when you access `example.com/rest/index.php/hello/droid`?

Comment: In the mean time I had realized what I was doing wrong - working through the fatigue barrier mainly.  In any case you are right.  I had a problem because I was doing something incorrect.  Browsing to example.com/rest/hello/droid gives just what I had expected. Put your comment as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you haven't defined a route for `/`, a request to `example.com/rest/index.php/hello/droid` and `example.com/rest/hello/droid` should work as expected.